# Create multiple instances of same OCX

Tags: .net, instance, ocx

I have to load a couple of OCX libraries to access legacy code. 
I am creating the instance using Activator.CreateInstance:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ProgId);
var comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Unfortunately **Activator.CreateInstance** seems to create only one instance per ProgId, however I need multiple instances with different configurations.

Example: Assuming I am using an OCX wich allows to set a value:

```
var instance1 = Create(progId);
Set(instance1, "key", "1");
var value1 = Get(instance1, "key"); // returns 1

var instance2 = Create(progId);
Set(instance2, "key", "2"); 
var value2 = Get(instance2, "key"); // returns 2

var value3 = Get(instance1, "key"); // returns 2
```

I need a way to instantiate one OCX (same ProgId) control multiple times without getting handed references to just one instance.

Comment: Could be a bug (global variables), could be intentional.  It usually is.  You have no knobs to tweak this, work with the OCX vendor.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The OCX is written by our company I think global variables may be the problem. I'll try to verify this notion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved by changing the OCX to not use global variables. Thanks Hans Passant.